# How to stop Google Chrome from automatically downloading plugins (e.g. Pepper flash player)

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I was reading a web page on Google Chrome a couple of days ago. Because of some new zero-day vulnerabilities, Google had disabled their Adobe Flash plugin and I was actually glad about that (because of less video adverts, etc.)

Anyway so while I was reading that page, I noticed that Symantec popped up a message saying that some "pepflashplayer.dll" was now downloaded and safe. The Symantec dialog contained a link to the downloaded item which had been placed in [Windows_user_account]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\18.0.0.209 as shown in below screen shot:

[image]

Now I do not particularly care of web browsers auto-installing software that I have not explicitly requested.

Is there a way to stop Google from auto-installing plugins (**not just the Pepper Flash player**), and if so, how?

Comment: Easiest option option i found is to disable google chrome update completely. not the best of the methods but should get your job done. There is one more trick for this but haven't tried it and it is kind of complicated. which one do you want to go for ?

Comment: I don't know how you can stop Chrome from adding *new* plugins (like when you install a new version of Chrome). But the existing ones can easily be disabled [by browsing to `chrome://plugins/`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1gITM.jpg) (Click "Details" for "Adobe Flash Player" to see this is indeed Pepper Flash. When manually installing Flash as well, you may see multiple entries for Flash.)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, what's the "one more trick" you are referring to? I would like to see if I can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest way is by using Windows security (ACL) to explicitly deny write and modify permissions to this folder:

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Although in this case you would not be able to view the contents of the folder either.

Comment: This might lead to lot of read write failure error messages on Chrome **+** i don't think anyone would go this route.